# How to customize android VideoView Error Dialogue

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-videoview

In my application i want to stream video. In case if mobile can not play that video `VideoView` shows dilogue like this
what i want if to customize this dialogue and insert two buttons one to download this video and one to try to play an `Low Quality` video.
right now in `onErrorLitener` of `VideoView` i am showing dialogue to user but in this way with my `dialogue` VideoView own dialogue also show on screen which i don't want.

If i cant customize `VideoView` Error dialogue can i make it dont show on screen

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem  @AkashG by putting your code in MediaPlay.setOnErrorListener()

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder=new Builder(YourActivityName.this);
        builder.setTitle("Video");
        builder.setMessage("Message you want to pass");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Download", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Play", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        builder.create();
        builder.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new Builder(YourActivityName.this);
        builder.setTitle("Video");
        builder.setMessage("Message you want to pass");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Download", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Play", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        builder.create();
        builder.show();
```

Just write code u wanna perform on download/play button click.

Comment: thanks for your reply but i dont want this i have already done this i want to override error dialogue

Comment: yes i know how i can customize it i dont want default behaviour

Comment: you can do by one way.you have to create custom media player and on error handler you can show the custom dialog layout.