# VideoView don't show error dialog

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am using below code to play video:

```
videoViewPlayer.setVideoPath(Video Path);
```

But if i try to play an unsuport video.
It will show the dialog `"Sorry, this video can not be played"`.
I does not want to show the dialog.
How can I do it?

Comment: What is the format of the video you are trying to play? And what version of Android are you testing on?

Comment: RU Running in Emulator?

Comment: I use an error mp4 file for test on Android 4.3 xperia z1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your video format not supported according to standard here mention : [See Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

then error will be prompt as dialog to you to notify.

now according to your need you want to handle error generation dialog by yourself 
then you need to implement OnErrorListener. either customize dialog yaa do nothing 
and you want do nothing :

see Following link this must be help you:

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407108/how-to-customize-android-videoview-error-dialogue)
[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742002/how-to-catch-sorry-this-video-cannot-be-played-error-on-videoview)
[Link 3](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#setOnErrorListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener%29)